# Is this "that" part of "on the grounds that?"

Tags: grammar

"Then, in the first place, do you agree with me that I have a right to be a little masterful, abrupt, perhaps exacting, sometimes, on the grounds I stated, namely, **that** I am old enough to be your father, and **that** I have battled through a varied experience with many men of many nations, and roamed over half the globe, while you have lived quietly with one set of people in one house?"[Source](http://www.loudlit.org/audio/jane_eyre/pages/14_12_jane_eyre.htm)

Is this "that" of "on the grounds?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, "that" refers to "the grounds I stated." This guy you're quoting is really on a rant! ^_^